# Can a generic $\mathbb{R}$ have a new cardinality?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, determinacy

*This question was [asked and bountied](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767428/could-the-post-forcing-continuum-be-a-new-cardinality) at MSE, without success.*

My main question is whether, starting with a model of determinacy, a "generic $\mathbb{R}$" could be different in cardinality from any ground model set:

> Is there a well-founded $V\models\mathsf{ZF+AD}$, a forcing $\mathbb{P}\in V$, and a $G$ which is $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $V$ such that $V[G]\models$ "There is no bijection between $\mathbb{R}^{V[G]}$ and any set in $V$"?

In case the answer is yes, there is a natural follow-up question - whether the above can happen "canonically:"

> Are there $V\models\mathsf{ZF+AD}$, $\mathbb{P}\in V$, and $G,H$ mutually $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $V$ such that $V[G\times H]$ satisfies "$\mathbb{R}^{V[G]}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{V[H]}$ *are* in bijection with each other but are not in bijection with any set in $V$?"

If the answer to *this* question is yes, that would give a very surprising answer to [this old question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/192314/a-new-cardinality-living-in-every-forcing-extension). I suspect that the first question has an affirmative answer and strongly suspect that the second question has a negative answer, but I don't see how to prove either point.

---

Here are a couple quick comments:

- Since this is only interesting if we add reals, [$\mathsf{AD}$ will not be preserved](https://mathoverflow.net/a/325782/8133). So determinacy doesn't give us a lot of "leverage" in the forcing extension that I can see.
- To preempt worries about triviality, we can have $V[G]\models$ "There is some $a$ which is not in bijection with any $b\in V$." For example, [Monro showed](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/on-generic-extensions-without-the-axiom-of-choice1/D2CAA61A488CD4A3644F272CBF6DB969) that we can have an amorphous set in $V[G]$ even if there are no amorphous sets in $V$; since amorphousness is downwards-absolute, any amorphous set in such a $V[G]$ is not (in $V[G]$, anyways) in bijection with any set in $V$. *(This reference was pointed out to me by Asaf Karagila.)*
- That said, questions of this type are always trivial over $\mathsf{ZFC}$ since forcing preserves choice and adds no new ordinals.
- But *that* said, the previous bulletpoint is quite fragile and I don't see that it gives any insight into my question - there's no obvious replacement for $Ord$ that I see here to serve the same role as something simultaneously "invariant" and "universal," especially since it would have to be "*generically* universal."

Comment: What reference would you indicate for a beginner in Logic willing to understand what is being asked? =]

Comment: @DryBones Unfortunately this really isn't accessible without a significant amount of experience - specifically, comfort with **forcing** is the key ingredient (although you also need to be comfortable with the axiom of determinacy, that's somewhat a secondary concern - the question is still interesting if we replace $\mathsf{ZF+AD}$ with just $\mathsf{ZF}$). Forcing is treated for example in Kunen's old book "Set theory and independence proofs;" [this](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~shac/forcing/forcing.html) and [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1320) are also good.

Comment: Forcing, however, relies on a mastery of the basics of set theory and model theory. So it's quite a long road.

Comment: Ok, I can imagine. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: @DryBones To be fair I might be overemphasizing the role of model theory. It's not really directly needed if you're willing to take a couple things on faith. However, the basic idea behind forcing is that we're building models of a certain very complicated theory (namely $\mathsf{ZF}$ or similar), and understanding basic properties of models will help dispel many (very reasonable) initial worries. So personally I wouldn't approach forcing without being comfortable with the downward Lowenheim-Skolem, compactness, completeness, and incompleteness theorems - the experience that confers will help.

Comment: I'm taking a look at Kunen's book and I like it! Though I'm still far from properly 'understanding' your question in detail, I'm compelled to ask if you know the answer for, say, ${\sf ZF}+\lnot{\sf AD}$. I mean, should the construction of $V[G]$ rely on some property of $V$ that depends on $V\models{\sf AD}$ ? Maybe this question doesn't make sense, but showing me why will probably help a bit on finding my way through this labyrinth! =]

Comment: @DryBones The construction of $V[G]$ makes sense as long as $V\models\mathsf{ZF}$ - or indeed **vastly** less ($\mathsf{KP}$ is more than enough). Per the end of my question, I know the answer - for silly reasons - if we consider $V\models\mathsf{ZFC}$. Meanwhile, I know basically nothing about what happens if we consider $V\models \mathsf{ZF+\neg AC}$. So why $\mathsf{AD}$? Well, many choiceless models are truly terrible (e.g. the reals can be a countable union of countable sets); amongst the $\mathsf{ZF+\neg AC}$-models, the $\mathsf{AD}$-models are in many ways very nicely behaved. (cont'd)

Comment: Moreover, determinacy models show up as natural submodels ("inner models") of choice models - e.g. assuming large cardinals, $L(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies $\mathsf{ZF+DC+AD}$. In a sense, determinacy is how choice fails "canonically." So looking at models of $\mathsf{ZF+AD}$ (or its ilk) is a natural thing to do here. Unfortunately, the question of how much we can conclude about $V[G]$ from knowing that $V\models\mathsf{AD}$ is a complicated one. In particular, unlike choice determinacy is not preserved by forcing. Forcing over $\mathsf{AD}$-models is as far as I'm aware still not well-understood.

Comment: Thanks, as expected your answer gives me a lot more to learn about! But if I got it partially, then it's not clear how $V\models{\sf AD}$ might help to choose $\Bbb P$ and $G$ with the desired properties, is that right?

Comment: @DryBones No it is not, at least to me. There are things one might try on the general grounds that they're usually relatively easy and instructive - e.g. [Cohen forcing](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368121/comparing-generic-versions-of-mathbbr) - but nothing stands out.